# Highlight panel error

Tags: page-layout

Can I have a formula and master-detail field inside highlight Panel on Page Layout? I have a master-detail and a formula field inside highlight panel on page layout. But Package installation fails due to this highlight panel. Any thoughts?
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the error your seeing during installation please.

Comment: Your requested install failed. Please try this again.

None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization should have been affected by this error.

If this error persists, contact salesforce.com Support through your normal channel.

Comment: After this I contacted salesforce and they told me that there is a problem in Highlight Panel.

Comment: @doga BTW: If you update your question with the additional data, it is more obvious to other readers.

Comment: Got it fixed. If you add any field to highlight panel then it has to be there on page-layout.

Comment: Aha good old dependency checking falling through the cracks. Have Salesforce confirmed from your case a bug has been raised for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encourage you to keep pressing Salesforce for more information, there will be an internal fault message relating to this, that they should be able to share in sanitised way or at least give you more information than you have apparently been given.  In the meantime here are some thoughts from our experience on dealing with this rather vague message.

- Consider what changes you made last to the package and back them out, one at a time. If you find the one that breaks it you can a) consider making this a post install step for the end user b) give Salesforce more information about the cause
- Manually check the dependencies of the component your adding, there has been bugs in the platform in the past where it does not bring in all the dependent components. For example check the other fields the formula field uses are included in the package as well.
- Try installing your package into other orgs with and without any previous versions of your package installed. Does the behaviour change?
- Check the dependencies of your package (View Dependencies button when viewing the package contents) against those in the target org your installing into. Again sometimes the platform does not give appropriate errors if these are not met.